# Is there any way to check from url if that file is already downloaded?

Tags: python, md5

> Suppose I have two urls which redirect to same file(hosted on 2 servers separately) and I've downloaded the file from one of the url. Is it possible to avoid downloading the same file again when I click the other url (checking in the system, if the file exists)?
>
> The main aim is to optimize data usage and remove redundancy.

I read about md5 checks for a file but can I calculate md5 checksum of a file on Internet without downloading it ?

Comment: You actually can't.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [**Etag**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) HTTP header.

> An ETag is an opaque identifier assigned by a web server to a specific
>   version of a resource found at a URL. If the resource representation
>   at that URL ever changes, a new and different ETag is assigned. Used
>   in this manner ETags are similar to fingerprints, and they can be
>   quickly compared to determine whether two representations of a
>   resource are the same.

However

> The use of ETags in the HTTP header is optional (not mandatory as with
>   some other fields of the HTTP 1.1 header). The method by which ETags
>   are generated has never been specified in the HTTP specification.

Comment: Will a ETag will be same for a file hosted on two separate servers with different names?

Comment: @Aaron2048 You cannot rely on that. As stated in the answer, ETag generation method is unspecified. Thus, different servers may use different methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to calculate a md5 hash without downloading the file, no.

What you can do though, is to check if the redirected url is the same, using the [`geturl()`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) method:

```
if urlopen(url1).geturl() == urlopen(url2).geturl():
    print("It's the same file")
```

Comment: what if the same file is hosted on two different servers and both servers have different url, but same file ?

Comment: @Aaron2048 There's no way to detect that, unfortunately.